How to make git autocomplete branch names for aliases
I have a couple of git alias in my ~/.gitconfig file, like so:
[alias]
  co = checkout
  dd = diff --relative --name-status

While in Bash, when I type git co <tab> I get a list of branches to complete. But when I type git dd <tab> I get a list of files instead. Notice that when I type git diff <tab> I also get a list of branches and tags.
After reading git-complete.bash code, I managed fix that placing the following code in my ~/.bashrc:
_git_dd() { _git_diff ; }

But it does not feel like the right way to fix that.

fwiw: creating your alias on my laptop does provide me the correct completion (branches + files) out of the box. You could activate set -x and debug what happens when you run git dd <tab> (without your _git_dd override)
